# System.FormatException convertir de string a char en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un programa en C# y me encuentro convirtiendo de string a char. Tengo una lista que la tengo definida de la siguiente forma

```
public static string[] salida;
```

y al momento de usarla, en que necesito convertirla a char, lo hago así:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sTipoDocumento", char.Parse(salida[i]));
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale un error:

> System.FormatException: La cadena debe contener exactamente un carácter

Se puede ampliar esto? que yo pueda definir el largo? Porque en mi base de datos (que no la puedo modificar yo) casi todos los campos están como char y de diferentes tamaños.

Sé que podría cambiar el tipo de lista a *char*, pero quiero evitar eso ya que en esta lista estoy guardando datos que saco de un archivo con substring de la siguiente forma:

```
salida[i] = line.Substring(Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida[0]), Int32.Parse(Datos.Psalida[1]));
```

Y me marca toda la linea en rojo con el mensaje: NO se puede convertir implícitamente de string a char.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Es lógico tu error, estas intentando convertir una cadena de texto de `n` caracteres a un char que almacena solo 1 caracter, en tu base de datos esta definido como varchar? o como es exactamente la definición de tu columna?

Comment: fijate que nunca me di cuenta ¬¬, ya pero hablando en serio, se puede definir de alguna forma eso?

Comment: Cual es la definición de tu columna en la base de datos? intenta también dejar un ejemplo de entrada/salida de información, sino es practicamente imposible ayudarte

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el tipo char o varchar de base de datos con el tipo char de C#. No son lo mismo. El equivalente es string en C#, asi que simplemente con `comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sTipoDocumento", salida[i]);`debería funcionarte correctamente

Comment: [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes?view=netframework-4.8) puedes consultar la equivalencia entre los tipos sqlserver y los nativos de C#

Comment: cual es el tipo de dato de la columna de la tabla donde mapea el parametro `@sTipoDocumento` ? La variable `salida` que valor le asignas?

Comment: en la base de datos el procedimiento dice **@sTipoDocumento char(2),**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La quizas la forma de convertir el string no sea la adecuada.

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
String salidaPos = salida[i];
char[] charSalida = salidaPos.ToCharArray(); 

comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sTipoDocumento", charSalida);
```

Sino debes comparar el tipo de dato que necesitas en la base.

Comment: Esto me funcionó, Muchas Gracias